# How to have multiple where clauses in SQL query

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2005

In the following query I am trying to get specifically a managers name using the 'not so looked up to' subquery. I am only using this subquery as I do not know how to specify another where clause for the 'ManagerID'

I understand that joins should be used in place of these queries as they operate row by row and not as a set but I don't see another way of doing this. Currently this query will not execute as I get the famous "subquery has returned multiple rows" Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT hrdh.StartDate
    ,hrdh.PositionTitle
    ,HumanResources.Department.NAME
    ,HumanResources.Employee.EmployeeNumber
    ,HumanResources.Employee.Classification
    ,HumanResources.Employee.STATUS
    ,HumanResources.Employee.ManagerID AS ManagerID
    ,Person.Contact.FirstName
    ,Person.Contact.LastName
    ,Person.Contact.SIN
    ,Person.Contact.DateOfBirth
    ,Person.Contact.PhoneNumber
    ,Person.Contact.EmailAddress
    ,Person.Contact.AddressLine1
    ,Person.Contact.AddressLine2
    ,Person.Contact.PostalCode
    ,Person.Contact.City
    ,Person.Contact.Province
    ,(
        SELECT (Person.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + Person.Contact.LastName) AS manager
        FROM Person.Contact
        INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee 
                ON Person.Contact.ContactID = HumanResources.Employee.ContactID
        WHERE HumanResources.Employee.ManagerID = ManagerID
        ) AS manager
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory hrdh
    ,HumanResources.Employee
    ,Person.Contact
    ,HumanResources.Department
WHERE hrdh.EmpID = @empID
```

Comment: boolean expressions, WHERE exp1 AND exp2

Comment: from where you get `ManagerID` for the inner select?

Comment: Can you post your db schema?

Comment: I get ManagerID from the HumanResources.Employee table , and then use that as the param for the inner select.

Also cannot post schema I know thatd help but i can make some of the tables up here if thatll help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper join conditions between all the tables. Below is just an approximation of the query as I don't know the table structures or key columns, but it is just to give an idea how it can be done.

```
SELECT 
   hrdh.StartDate, hrdh.PositionTitle, d.Name,
   e.EmployeeNumber, e.Classification, e.Status,
   e.ManagerID AS ManagerID, c1.FirstName, c1.LastName, c1.SIN,
   c1.DateOfBirth, c1.PhoneNumber, c1.EmailAddress, c1.AddressLine1,
   c1.AddressLine2, c1.PostalCode, c1.City, c1.Province,
   (c2.FirstName+ ' ' + c2.LastName) AS manager
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory hrdh 
    join HumanResources.Employee e on hrdh.keycolumn = e.keycolumn
    join Person.Contact c1 on e.ContactID = c1.ContactID
    join Person.Contact c2 on e.ManagerID = c2.ContactID
    join HumanResources.Department d on d.keycolumn = e.keycolumn
WHERE 
    hrdh.EmpID = @empID
```

Comment: Ok this is looking clean I think I can make sense of this and massage it to my exact specifications.

Thanks a lot !